# The Browser block javascripts on site loaded from Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I code a small tool to load an HTML page to an iframe. I wrote a little javascripts code to get XPath from element which I clicked.
But the problem is that the tool run smoothly with html page I wrote to test. But when I load an external site from internet, the tool doesn't work. Nothing happen. I think the browser disabled javascripts from external HTML Page. Can you help me to solve that problems.

Comment: Have a look at [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Does your site and the remote link are the same protocol?
HTTP and HTTS

iframe can not load HTML from different protocol with main site.

Comment: Need more context on exactly how you are loading the iframe in the other source, and the differences between the sources. As mentioned by both mapek and Pekka, cross site scripting has to be secure, otherwise browsers will prevent the script from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers block cross site scripting (XSS) like that. Meaning that you can't handle events at external sites/pages.

However, you should be able to run the tool if the page with iframe and the iframe's content page are located under the same domain. That's why your test works.

Comment: Ok, tks you very much. Can you suggest me some solution? Please help me

Comment: Unfortunately solutions for these problems are so context sensitive that I cannot say what you should do. I can assure, you're not the first (nor the last) one who gets to fight with this problem. Since we don't have your code and we don't know what you are ultimately trying to achieve with your tool, we cannot give any specific advice. Usually these problems lead into refactoring the whole idea of "what are we doing" and "why we do it".